# n-Body Simulation Phantom Forces

Tags: java, simulation, game-physics

In my n-Body Simulation I have about 1k particles which fly around. I store the positions as floats. A problem I have is that every time I run the code, when two particles get really close to eachother (essentially the same position), they are extremely accelerated. Normally particles behave smoothly.

```
if((planet.position.x != otherPlanet.position.x && planet.position.y != otherPlanet.position.y) && !otherPlanet.delete)
        {
            //First we get the x,y and magnitudal distance between the two bodies.
            float xDist = (otherPlanet.position.x - planet.position.x);
            float yDist = (otherPlanet.position.y - planet.position.y);
            float dist = Vector2Math.distance(planet.position, otherPlanet.position);

            //Now we compute first the total and then the component forces
            //Depending on choice, use r or r^2
            float force = Constants.GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT * ((planet.mass*otherPlanet.mass)/(dist*dist)); 
            float forceX = force * xDist/dist;
            float forceY = force * yDist/dist;

            //Given the component forces, we construct the force vector and apply it to the body.
            Vector2 forceVec = new Vector2(forceX, forceY);
            planet.force = Vector2Math.add(planet.force, forceVec);
            otherPlanet.force = Vector2Math.subtract(otherPlanet.force, forceVec);
        }
```

I haven't found anything on this topic, but is this something I'm doin wrong on my part or do I have to implement a max acceleration or a minimum distance between the particles?

Comment: "when two particles get really close to eachother, they just explode outwards at breakneck speeds." this doesn't mean anything in this context, I suggest you rephrase your problem

Comment: @DPM i think that it clearly describes the problem

Comment: "really close", explode, breakneck and outwards doesn't mean anything at the level of abstraction of 10 lines of java code.

Comment: Yes guys I edited it long ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulated world is a bit different from the real world, and in order to make a good simulation we need to add some restriction.

**Problem:**

> When two particles get really close to each other, they just explode
>   outwards at breakneck speeds.

**Cause**

> The reason for this is simple force of gravity is inversely
>   proportional to distant squared between two bodies. When the two
>   bodies come too close ,radius (distance between them) becomes very less
>   and the force acting on them become very very large.

**Solution**

> Add a virtual limit on how much close two particles can come.By
>   virtual limit i mean that the limit is only on the values but not on
>   the simulation.For ex. if the distance between them is less than 5(a
>   threshold) set the distance to 5.

**Changes in your code**

```
if((planet.position.x != otherPlanet.position.x && planet.position.y != otherPlanet.position.y) && !otherPlanet.delete)
        {
            //First we get the x,y and magnitudal distance between the two bodies.
            float xDist = (otherPlanet.position.x - planet.position.x);
            float yDist = (otherPlanet.position.y - planet.position.y);
             // add a limit to xDist and yDist
             if(xDist<5)
                xDist=5;
             if(yDist<5)
                yDist=5;
            float dist = Vector2Math.distance(planet.position, otherPlanet.position);

            //Now we compute first the total and then the component forces
            //Depending on choice, use r or r^2
            float force = Constants.GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT * ((planet.mass*otherPlanet.mass)/(dist*dist)); 
            float forceX = force * xDist/dist;
            float forceY = force * yDist/dist;

            //Given the component forces, we construct the force vector and apply it to the body.
            Vector2 forceVec = new Vector2(forceX, forceY);
            planet.force = Vector2Math.add(planet.force, forceVec);
            otherPlanet.force = Vector2Math.subtract(otherPlanet.force, forceVec);
        }
```

Of course you want to change that 5 to a value that suites you simulation.